# Using Objects as keys in Java HashMap

Tags: java

```
package test;

import java.util.HashMap;

public class test {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        HashMap<ID, String> h = new HashMap<ID, String> ();
        String b;

        ID id1 = new ID(100);
        ID id2 = new ID(200);
        ID id3 = new ID(200);

        h.put(id1, "apple");
        h.put(id2, "pear");

        **System.out.println(h.containsKey(id3));**
    }
}

class ID {
    Integer code;

    public ID(Integer id) {
        this.code = id;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode()
    {
        return code.hashCode();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o)
    {
        return this.code.equals(o);
    }
}
```

the output of this program is "false". I can't understand of this result. I implemented hashCode and equals which are overrided. I don't have an idea how to solve. How to use objects as keys in java HashMap?

Comment: @saka1029 He puts another `ID` instance with the same integer value. So it should print *"true"* if he fixes his problem in the `equals` method.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your equals implementation is wrong :

```
public boolean equals(Object o)
{
    return this.code.equals(o); // this will never return true,
                                // since you are comparing an Integer instance
                                // to an ID instance
}
```

You should compare this code to the other code:

```
public boolean equals(Object o)
{
    if (!(o instanceof ID))
        return false;
    ID oid = (ID) o;
    return this.code.equals(oid.code);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrong Implementation of `equals` method. According to your implementation it executes the `Integer` class equals method. We should handle the logic without execute library classes `equals` methods.

```
@Override 
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (o == null || ((o instanceof ID) && o.hashCode() != this.hashCode())) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```